# Compiling GCC 4.7.3 for i386-elf support on Cygwin

Tags: gcc, cygwin, elf

I am trying to compile GCC for Cygwin with support for targeting i386-elf so I can compile some simple OSes (search Benu, by l30nard0, on Github). I've successfully compiled the binutils for i386-elf, and compiled all of GCC's floating-point numbers dependencies.

Problem is, it says windows.h can not be found. I do have w32api successfully installed, and tried including each of those one at a time in the include path for GCC, but none of them work. If I try any of them, I get so many errors and warnings that not all will show up in the Cygwin console. The dozens upon dozens of warnings are most if not all `unused parameter`.

Does anyone know where the problem might lie?

I've wasted the last three entire days of my life trying to get Linux Mint set up with everything I want, but for reasons I shan't go into I gave up on that. I'd love to be able to get just one thing to work so I can enjoy my life again. :) Thanks!

BTW: The configure arguments I used were `--target=i386-elf --enable-threads=win32 --enable-languages=c,c++` Was I supposed to use `--enable-targets` instead?

And here's part of the log:

```
In file included from ../../../gcc/libgcc/gthr.h:150:0,
             from ../../../gcc/libgcc/unwind-dw2.c:38:
./gthr-default.h:541:21: fatal error: windows.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
../../../gcc/libgcc/static-object.mk:17: recipe for target 'unwind-dw2.o' failed
make[2]: *** [unwind-dw2.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from ../../../gcc/libgcc/gthr.h:150:0,
             from ../../../gcc/libgcc/unwind-dw2-fde.c:38:
./gthr-default.h:541:21: fatal error: windows.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
../../../gcc/libgcc/static-object.mk:17: recipe for target 'unwind-dw2-fde.o' failed
make[2]: *** [unwind-dw2-fde.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/Sean/gccbuild/i386-elf/libgcc'
Makefile:10055: recipe for target 'all-target-libgcc' failed
make[1]: *** [all-target-libgcc] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/Sean/gccbuild'
Makefile:870: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `--enable-threads=win32` flag; it is intended to specify thread support on the **target** system, not the build system.

Comment: Thanks! I got rid of that, but many other problems came up, but I fixed them all!